# Using public string from class in whole project (translatefile)

Tags: c#, localization

I am currently working on a website in different language. I know it is not the perfect way to do it, but this is how it works now:

```
public string Donkerblauw = LanguageFile.Language("Donkerblauw", taal);
public string Lichtblauw = LanguageFile.Language("Lichtblauw", taal);
public string Groen = LanguageFile.Language("Groen", taal);
```

It's not picking the string from the language DB with the current taal(language) It is declared in a class called `BaseMasterPage`

To use it, i usE:

```
public partial class MasterPage : BaseMasterPage
```

Working fine, but when i want to use it in other pages, i have to declare all the strings again. I have tried static strings, but they have a delay before they are updated.

How can i use this strings without declaring them on each page mand without making SQL calls on each page?

Comment: static strings do not have any 'delay'.

Comment: if you don't prefer to use static strings, try to store them in `Application` or in `Cache`

Comment: Do you use Google Chrome? The Chrome has aggressive cache policy, try to press CTRL + F5 multiple times quickly to update page.

Comment: i use a cookie that stores the lang choice. When i set the strings to static, it takes a few minutes before the lang changes. When i change the code file it changes directly after a refresh. CTRL + F5 wont work. In all the browsers there is a delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some static string around the pages you can simply store it in the web.Config file and use it.
Otherwise you can have another class to call these.